# How to set up fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId and fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey in SparkR?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I am trying to access parquet file stored in S3 bucket using sparkR with spark 2.1.

I tried to set up the aws secrets this way.

```
Sys.setenv(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="XXXX")
Sys.setenv(AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="XXXX")
```

But it return an error :

> Error: Error in loadDF : illegal argument - AWS Access Key ID and
>   Secret Access Key must be specified as the username or password
>   (respectively) of a s3 URL, or by setting the fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId or
>   fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey properties (respectively).

Comment: Did you find your answer ?

Comment: do you have the AWS command line tool installed?

Answer (score 1):

Passing your credentials directly into the requested url doesn't fire the error.

`s3n://XXXX:XXXX@bucket/file/whateveryouwant` with XXXX:XXXX being your aws_access_key_id:aws_secret_access_key